# Putting HTTP Request Body inside "data" : {}?

Tags: ios, json, swift, networking

I want my request to have the structure:

```
{
   "data": {
      "key": "value"
   }
}
```

However currently it'll just send

```
{
   "key": "value"
}
```

My code is:

```
let data: Data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reqDict, options: [])
```

Where reqDict is a dictionary

then:

```
var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpBody = data
```

How do I achieve the "data": wrapper around the whole request as my server expects? Do I need to create a custom "request" object that contains the dictionary to create this value? or is it something I can do in the rest client for all requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let content:[String:Any] = ["data":reqDict]
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: content, options: [])
```

Comment: yep this works, I wasn't sure if it was this simple or if its too sledgehammer to add this on ALL my api requests in this manner